# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore": In snapshot (Podfile.lock)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, podfile

I'm trying to add the [Geofirestore](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/Geofirestore-ios) pod I found on GitHub So I can add geo locations longitude and latitude to posts in a social media app. My pod file looks like this

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Geofirestore'
```

I ran the pod repo update and pod install in my terminal but its not working and I'm getting this as an error.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseCore (= 4.0.20, ~> 4.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core was resolved to 4.13.0, which depends on
      FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
        FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)

    Firebase/Core was resolved to 4.13.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCore (= 4.0.20)

    Geofirestore was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCore (~> 5.0.3)

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `11.4` on target `My App` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have `'Geofirestore'` in your Podfile: as seen by the error message, it requires `FirebaseCore (~> 5.0.3)`.

You have `'Firebase/Storage', '~> 4.0'` in your Podfile, which sticks you to `FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)`.

To use both, you'll need to upgrade from Firebase 4 to Firebase 5. I.e. you need to have:

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.0'
```

Comment: Ahh I forgot that having a older version of one pod for firebase effects the rest too. Thank you so much, I will update my firebase pods.

Comment: Nice I didn't know that!